# iOS 14 Crash when setting label line break mode, text alignment and text color

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I've been using React Native SVG for a project and with the upgrade to iOS 14 I've started to receive a crash on a resizable box. I've tracked the crash down to three assignments in a library but am unsure of why they cause a `EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` or a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

This crash occurs only after the initial render within the app when you resize the box. The first render is fine and then the subsequent move of the item causes the fault. This code worked in iOS 13 but does not in iOS 14.

I've created a reproducible example [here](https://github.com/kennyLtv/svg-reproducable). I've also created an issue on the repo [here](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/issues/1480).

In the library I've attempted to hard code the assignments to known good values assuming something went wrong with how they were being assigned with no luck.

The following is where I receive the error:

```
label.attributedText = (__bridge NSAttributedString * _Nullable)(attrString);
label.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentNone;
//label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
//label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.opaque = NO;
label.font = font;
//label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:color];
```

This is from [line 203 in RNSVGTSpan](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/blob/develop/ios/Text/RNSVGTSpan.m#L203), the comments are the lines I've removed to make it work but this takes away functionality that is used.

I'm at a loss as to why this would work on the initial render but not with the subsequent changes in iOS 14 but works flawlessly in iOS 13.

Comment: On which line do you get the crash?

Comment: The crash is on like 203 in RNSVGTSpan, I've explored further in the last little while and found that changing the `attributedText` to text and providing the string directly also remedies my crash. I'm looking at if the attributedString is receiving an incorrect value somehow. Also, RNSVGTSpan is from React Native SVG and isn't something I wrote but am trying to fix.

Comment: So that's the first line of you code snippet above. Did you check if `attrString` is valid? That could cause a crash if it is not.

Comment: I've not confirmed yet that is is valid but that is what i'm currently looking into is if that `attrString` is or isn't valid. I'm also looking at potentially just replacing it with `text` since it's got the same values being set afterwords that are in the `attrString` for the most part.